# EBNF: prefix and suffix-like operator in assembly code production

Tags: ebnf

I'm trying to write down [6809 assembly](http://datapipe-blackbeltsystems.com/windows/flex/asm4.html) in EBNF to write a [tree-sitter](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter) parser.

I'm stuck on one certain production. In 6809 assembly, you can use a register as an operand and additionally de- or increment it:

```
LDA 0,X+     ; loads A from X then bumps X by 1
LDD ,Y++     ; loads D from Y then bumps Y by 2
LDA 0,-U     ; decrements U by 1 then loads A from address in U
LDU ,--S     ; decrements S by 2 then loads U from address in S
```

Mind the "missing" first operand in the second line of code. Here are the productions I wrote:

```
instruction = opcode, [operand], ["," , register_exp];
...
register_exp = [{operator}], register | register, [{operator}];
register = "X" | "Y" | "U" | etc. ;
operator = "+" | "-";
```

The problem is `register_exp = ...`. I feel like there could be a more elegant way to define this production. Also, what happens if only a register is given to `register_exp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need

```
register_exp = [{operator}], register | register, [{operator}] | register;
```

to allow register names without operators. Why do you find it not so elegant? Quite descriptive.

Comment: it feels redundive, but the added `| register` solves my other problem, thanks!

Comment: My guess is, trying to hack it more compact would finally result in much more monstrous subroutines, so better left as is. :)